After saving an Excel file, using C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, it is being opened in Safe mode afterwards
So, I have this method which exports some data into an Excel file:
public void exportToExcel(string filePath, string sheetName)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook workBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly : false);
    Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets[sheetName];

    int x = 1;

    foreach (string plotName in plotNames)
    {
        x += 2;

        foreach (string property in plotProperties[plotName])
        {
            x += 1;

            foreach (Area area in AreasOrganizer[plotName][property])
            {
                try
                {
                    Range cellRangeString = workSheet.Range[$"A{x}", $"B{x}"];
                    Range cellRangeDouble = workSheet.Range[$"C{x}", $"X{x}"];

                    /* configuring data to be written */

                    string[] areaStringData = new[] { areaNumber, areaName };
                    double[] areasDoubleData = new[] { areaArea, areaSubjected, ACGA, ACOR, ACLE, ACLO, ACHE, ACRO, ACSP, ACST, ACZO, ACCO, C1C2, areaCommonPercent, areaCommonArea, areaTotalArea, areaPermitPercent, areaRLPPercentage, areaRLP };

                    cellRangeString.set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, areaStringData);
                    cellRangeDouble.set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, areasDoubleData);                            
                }
                catch
                {
                    Range cellRangeString = workSheet.Range[$"A{x}", $"B{x}"];
                    string[] cellsStrings = new[] { "X", "Y" };
                    cellRangeString.set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, cellsStrings);
                }

                x += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    workBook.Save();
    workBook.Close();
}

The method works just fine, but once I try to open the file manually afterwards, it asks to be opened in Safe Mode:
click here to view screenshot
It's not a big deal, but it's just a bit annoying, so if anyone knows how to fix this, that would be awesome! It's the first time I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. And I don't think the problem comes from internal Excel configuration, as it only happens when I edit the file from my plug in and never when doing it manually :) thanks in advance!
